# Possible Chrome bug: Docking a div outside the body makes the scrollbar inaccessible

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, scrollbar, docking

I'm writing a Chrome extension that involves appending an iframe as the sibling of an existing page's body, reducing the height of the body to stay above the iframe, and setting the overflow of the html and body tags to "scroll". Example here:
http://output.jsbin.com/cetobu/1
This creates two vertical scrollbars: one for the html tag (the longer one) and one for the body. However, the scrollTop property of "body" reports the value for the "html" scrollbar, and none of the elements reflect the "body" scrollbar. This is a huge problem because the extension needs to be able to set the scrollTop value of the body, but the only scrollbar I can get to is the "html" one. How do I access the "body" scrollbar?
(In Firefox, html.scrollTop and body.scrollTop reflect the correct scrollbars.)

Alternatively, if anyone knows a different way to insert an element on an existing page and have everything else move out of the way, that would be great. (I've tried wrapping the whole content of the body in a new div and putting my iframe in as its sibling, but it caused a lot of different complications on different sites.)

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a known issue in Chrome. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=157855 https://dev.opera.com/articles/fixing-the-scrolltop-bug/

Comment: So is there nothing I can do about this? The "fixes" on the Dev.Opera site are just about browser compatibility.